# Can't get Android Studio to sync Google Glass project

Tags: android, google-glass

This is my first time out on the site and also with Android studio, so admittedly, these may be very simple answers that I'm missing but I've got a couple problems going on and I think they're all related. First, Android studio doesn't recognize the glass when it's plugged in via usb. My computer recognizes it and I can find it in the device manager and it says it has the most up to date drivers installed. I emailed support and got back some code I had to insert into AndroidManifest.xml which I inserted but, still Android Studio can't find it.

I've been looking around online quite a bit and it looks like every project is supposed to have an activity_main.xml file under app/src/main/res/layout but I don't have this folder or file at all. Is that a problem and if so, can I just insert a folder and/or file? Would I need to rebuild the project again for it to be usable?

Also, when it tries to build it immediately gets hung up and the error is 'The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well informed. I don't have any idea what this means or how to fix it. Perhaps this has something to do with not having an activity_main.xml?

This is what I've got in the Android Manifest

```
<<<<<<<Original<manifestxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.admin.helloglass">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>

</manifest>

    =======<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT"/>

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_glass_logo">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="com.google.android.glass.category.DIRECTORY"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
        android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger" />
</activity>
```

```
</manifest>>>>>>>> Added
```

Thanks for your help.